# OpenXML created SpreadSheet found unreadable content

Tags: c#, openxml

I am creating an Excel file with OpenXML file as follows

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dic1 = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"H1","FPT1" },
            {"AA1","IPN1" },
        };

        Dictionary<string, string> dic2 = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"H2","FPT2" },
            {"AA2","IPN2" },
        };
        Dictionary<string, string> dic3 = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"H3","FPT3" },
            {"AA3","IPN3" },
        };
        Dictionary<string, string> dic4 = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"H4","FPT4" },
            {"AA4","IPN4" },
        };
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> data = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        data.Add(dic1);
        data.Add(dic2);
        data.Add(dic3);
        data.Add(dic4);

        CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook(@"J:\OpenXMLApp\Myfile.xlsx", data);
    }

    public static void CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook(string filepath, List<Dictionary<string, string>> Data)
    {
        // Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
        // By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
        SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

        // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
        WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
        workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

        // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

        // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
        Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

        // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
        Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "mySheet" };
        sheets.Append(sheet);

        // Get the sheetData cell table.
        SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

        int rowindex = 2;
        foreach (Dictionary<string, string> _row in Data)
        {
            Row row = new Row
            {
                RowIndex = (uint)rowindex
            };
            sheetData.Append(row);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in _row)
            {
                string CellAddressForCurrentAttribute = string.Empty;

                Cell refcell = row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => string.Compare(c.CellReference.Value, CellAddressForCurrentAttribute, true) == 0).FirstOrDefault();
                Cell newCell = new Cell { CellReference = pair.Key };
                newCell.InlineString = new InlineString() { Text = new Text(pair.Value) };
                newCell.DataType = CellValues.SharedString;
                row.InsertBefore(newCell, refcell);
            }
        }
        rowindex++;
        spreadsheetDocument.Save();
        // Close the document.
        spreadsheetDocument.Close();
    }
}
```

Now when I open the Excel file created by above code I get the below Error..
[image: Excel Error]

In the log file I get as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
   <logFileName>error199640_01.xml</logFileName>
   <summary>Errors were detected in file 'J:\OpenXMLApp\Myfile.xlsx'</summary>
   <removedRecords>
      <removedRecord>Removed Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part</removedRecord>
   </removedRecords>
   <repairedRecords>
      <repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part</repairedRecord>
   </repairedRecords>
</recoveryLog>
```

what was the problem with OpenXML in generating the Excel file? I am using the sample snippet from MSDN website [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-create-a-spreadsheet-document-by-providing-a-file-name) ................................................

Answer (score 0):

OpenXML is like a stubborn girlfriend. It needs things to be done in a particular way and if you change even the slightest thing, it will break-up.

Please find the modified code below which hopefully works the way you want it. I have tested it and it generates output without giving any errors.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dic1 = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"H2","FPT1" },
            {"AA2","IPN1" },
        };

            var dic2 = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"H3","FPT2" },
            {"AA3","IPN2" },
        };
            var dic3 = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"H4","FPT3" },
            {"AA4","IPN3" },
        };
            var dic4 = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"H5","FPT4" },
            {"AA5","IPN4" },
        };
            var data = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>
            {
                dic1,
                dic2,
                dic3,
                dic4
            };

            CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook(@"J:\OpenXMLApp\Myfile.xlsx", data);
        }

        public static void CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook(string filepath, List<Dictionary<string, string>> Data)
        {
            // Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
            // By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
            var spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

            // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
            var workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
            workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

            // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
            var sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

            // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
            var worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            // Get the sheetData cell table.
            var sheetData = new SheetData();
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();

            var rowindex = 2;
            foreach (var _row in Data)
            {
                var row = new Row
                {
                    RowIndex = (uint)rowindex
                };
                foreach (var pair in _row)
                {
                    var newCell = new Cell { CellReference = pair.Key, DataType = CellValues.InlineString };
                    var inlineString = new InlineString();
                    var t = new Text
                    {
                        Text = pair.Value
                    };
                    inlineString.AppendChild(t);
                    newCell.AppendChild(inlineString);
                    row.AppendChild(newCell);
                }
                sheetData.AppendChild(row);
                rowindex++;
            }

            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(sheetData);

            // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
            var sheet = new Sheet() { Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "mySheet" };
            sheets.Append(sheet);

            spreadsheetDocument.Save();
            // Close the document.
            spreadsheetDocument.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I still see the same issue with this Code as well..:(

Comment: That is strange, it is working fine for me on target framework 4.7.2 with DocumentFormat.OpenXml nuget version 2.9.1 and opening the xlsx file in Excel 2013. What does your environment look like? Did you run the code as it is without any change?

Comment: Yes..I copy pasted your code to see if it works...I have .net 4.7 and OpenXML is `<package id="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" version="2.9.1" targetFramework="net47" />` I am opening Excel file in Office365. I tried in Excel 2013 and 2010 and still get the same issue